# Why MySQL doesn't use the index

Tags: mysql

I'm running these two different queries and I don't understand why on the first one sale table index is not used

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(`sale`.`saleId`) AS `nb`
FROM `sale` 
WHERE `sale`.`saleTransactionId` IN (
SELECT `transaction`.`transactionId`
FROM `transaction`  
WHERE `transaction`.`transactionId` = 87587
)
```

Result is

[result 1 http://snag.gy/SusqF.jpg](http://snag.gy/SusqF.jpg)

Second one

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(`sale`.`saleId`) AS `nb`
FROM `sale` 
WHERE `sale`.`saleTransactionId` IN (87587)
```

Result is

[result 2 http://snag.gy/ZgOXQ.jpg](http://snag.gy/ZgOXQ.jpg)

Juste to be sure

```
SELECT `transaction`.`transactionId`
FROM `transaction`  
WHERE `transaction`.`transactionId` = 87587
```

returns juste one row

saleTransactionId is INT(11) as transactionId
Both tables uses MyISAM

And sale index structure

[sale index structure http://snag.gy/we3HL.jpg](http://snag.gy/we3HL.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the subquery is a *dependent subquery* (due to how MySQL works).  This means that the result of the inner query depends on the outer query.  Thus, an index cannot be used for the outer query since the inner query relies on its results.  Sounds counter intuitive, but that's what's happening.

As for a solution: don't use a subquery.  Use a JOIN.

```
SELECT COUNT(saleId) AS nb
FROM sale
JOIN transaction ON (saleTransactionId = transactionId)
WHERE transactionId = 87587
```